# What does void function in C return?

Tags: c, function

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()

{

    int k = m();

    printf("%d", k);

}

void m()

{

    printf("hello");

}
```

**Output**
`hello5`

What is the void function returning here?
If there is no printf() then the output is `1`.
What is happening here?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c

Comment: Until you are substantially more skilled at C and know when it is inappropriate, *always* invoke GCC with its `-Wall` option.  That means "enable all of the warnings that should be on by default but, for compatibility's sake, aren't."  (There are even more warnings available if you want them, but they have much higher false-positive rates.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `void` function does not return anything. Your program invokes undefined behavior because it implicitly defines `m` to have return type `int` (in C89, if a function is called before it is declared, it's implicitly assumed to have return type `int`), but then defines it with return type `void`.

If you add a forward-declaration for `m`, the compiler will correctly complain that you're trying to use the return value of a void function, which is not possible.

Comment: What's actually happening (although there's no guarantee of consistency) is that `main` is getting the return value left behind by `printf` (which is 5 because it printed 5 characters).

Answer (score 4):

In both cases (`void m` with caller expecting `int`, `void main` with caller-in-C-library expecting `int`), this is undefined behavior, and your compiler should have chewed you out, e.g. [GCC 4.8 with -Wall]:

```
test.c:3:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
 void main()
      ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘m’
     int k = m();
     ^
test.c: At top level:
test.c:13:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘m’
 void m()
      ^
test.c:7:13: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘m’ was here
     int k = m();
             ^
```

"Implicit declarations" exist only for backward compatibility with pre-C1989 programs, which are more than 20 years out of date at this point.  If you had written this code in a more modern style you would've gotten a hard error:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void m(void);

int main(void)
{
    int k = m();
    printf("%d", k);
    return 0;
}

void m(void)
{
    printf("hello");
}
```

⇒

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:7:13: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
     int k = m();
             ^
```

The key addition is the `extern void m(void);` line.  The compiler isn't allowed to look ahead to the definition of `m` when it checks `main` for errors, so you need a forward declaration to tell it what `m`'s type really is.  You should also know that in C (but not C++), `void m()` means "`m` takes *an unspecified number* of arguments".  To declare a function taking *no* arguments, which is what you wanted, you have to write `void m(void)`.

I believe what is happening on your specific system is that the return value of `printf`, which your code officially ignores, is being left in the return-value register and thus interpreted as the return value of `m`, but *you cannot rely on anything predictable happening*.  That is what 'undefined behavior' means.

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior.

The reason the compiler lets you do the assignment is that there is no prototype of `m` available to it. When this happens, C standard says that the function must return `int`. Since in this case the actual function return type is `void`, the behavior is undefined. The value that you get in variable `k` is entirely arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The return value of a function usually stored in the one of the CPU registers, EAX for x86. As C it just a friendly assembler, you can always read the value from the register. And you will get whatever was there. Efficiently, int k = m() tells program to store value of register EAX in the variable k.

Answer (score 0):

You have not declared `void m();` before calling it in `main`.

Some compilers assume the return type of unknown function symbols as `int` (unknown at the time of compilation of course) . In fact, your compiler has probably issued a compilation warning on this.

If you declare this function **before** `main` (where it **should** be declared), then you will probably get a compilation error.